# How does "Noindex:" in robots.txt work?

Tags: web-crawlers, robots.txt, googlebot, noindex

I ran across [this article](https://www.seroundtable.com/google-do-not-use-noindex-in-robots-txt-20873.html) in my SEO news today.   It seems to imply that you can you use `Noindex:` directives in addition to the standard `Disallow:` directives in *robots.txt*.

```
Disallow: /page-one.html
Noindex: /page-two.html
```

Seems like it would prevent search engines from crawling page one, and prevent them from indexing page two.

Is this *robots.txt* directive supported by Google and other search engines?   Does it work?  Is it documented?

Comment: I dunno... bu this could be very helpful for some. As well, I would like to see the sitemap expanded to be more communicative. Between robots and sitemaps, this should be a golden opportunity to communicate back to search engines and others about a site. I am also in favor of a text based opportunity to inform search engines about the site in a different way separate from being available in search such as the about page as if you got the chance to talk directly to a Google site reviewer. It could save some heart-aches and misunderstandings. A chance to say Ooopppsss, I goofed- Sorry.

Comment: I'm under the impression that `disallow` stops Google discovering links on the parent and child pages if any exist. While `noindex` simply stops the page being listed, it doesn't stop discovery while disallow does.

Comment: @SimonHayter I know that is how `nofollow` works for meta tags. It would be nice to know if that is also the case for *robots.txt*.

Comment: Hey @StephenOstermiller not only meta tags, its the same for `<a  rel="no-follow">` too. I see no reason why it would be treated any different. Obviously this isn't official and its even recommended by John Muller not to use it in the robots.txt but other than his tweet I haven't managed to find much information about it.

Comment: It's worth noting that Google no longer flags the `Noindex` directive within `robots.txt` files as an error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Google used to unofficially support a `Noindex` directive in robots.txt, however in 2019, [they announced](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2019/07/a-note-on-unsupported-rules-in-robotstxt.html) that the directive will no longer work.

Here is what Google's [John Mueller says about `Noindex:` in *robots.txt*](https://youtu.be/yIIRyBMSPUk?t=47m58s):

> We used to support the no-index directive in robots.txt
>   as an experimental feature.
>   But it's something that I wouldn't rely on.
>   And I don't think other search engines are using that at all.

[Before Google announced the feature was discontinued, deepcrawl.com did some testing of the feature](https://www.deepcrawl.com/knowledge/best-practice/robots-txt-noindex-the-best-kept-secret-in-seo/) and discovered that:

- Before 2019, it still worked with Google
- It prevented URLs from appearing in the search index
- URLs that have been noindexed in *robots.txt* were marked as such in Google Search Console

Given that Google discontinued the feature, it shouldn't be used anymore.

Instead, use robots meta tags that are [well supported and documented](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_meta_tag)  to prevent indexing:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex" />
```