# Google is trying to index the mail.mydomain.example domain and says this is a coverage issue

Tags: google, search-engine-indexing, robots.txt

I have sub domains for my domains. `mail.mydomain.example`, `ftp.mydomain.example`, etc. These sub domains are configured with the DNS server for the domains.

**Without doing anything on my part Google went and tried to index 
`http://mail.mydomain.example`**

They then sent me the following message:

```
New Coverage issue detected
Search Console has identified that your site is affected by 1 new Coverage 
related issue. This means that Coverage may be negatively affected in Google 
Search results. We encourage you to fix this issue.

New issue found:
Indexed, though blocked by robots.txt
```

I have no `robots.txt` for `mail.mydomain.example` or my existing `robots.txt` does not give any mention of `robots.txt`

Any ideas how I can fix this so that Google does not see it as a "coverage issue"? In my book when you own important web sites and Google has some kind of issue you better make sure it has no issue because web site traffic depends on Google being happy.

Comment: Dup of [How to resolve Google “Indexed, though blocked by robots.txt”](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/117744/how-to-resolve-google-indexed-though-blocked-by-robots-txt)?

Comment: The circumstances is a bit different, although the question is more or less the same.

Comment: mail.example.com is typically a host/MX record in DNS. Is there a reason for making it a sub domain?