# Google is ignoring meta tags and robots.txt

Tags: google-search-console, googlebot, robots.txt, meta-tags

I have the following meta tags on my website (dev server):

```
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex">
  <meta name="googlebot" content="noindex">
```

And I also configured a `robots.txt` (validated).
However, on Google Search Console, I can still search for content and get A LOT of results on Google, as other people on my team.

This is what I get on Google Search Console:
[image]

[image]

Robots file (www root folder)

```
Disallow: /
Disallow: /frontend/
Disallow: /frontend
Allow: /login/
Allow: /login
Allow: /portal/
Allow: /portal
Allow: /store/
Allow: /store
```

I basically have one server with 3 folders (4 projects):

1. Login is a SSO
2. portal is a user portal
3. store is and eCommerce.
4. front-end is a pure static front-end without password and logic of the other 3 folders (dev sandbox). This is the one I'm trying to block Google keeps indexing.

After reading more about the subject and per the suggestion I removed robots.the text completely from the server file and maintained the meta tags.

After that, I forced removal and crawling:

- https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/removals
- https://search.google.com

Result: it keeps indexing and I can still find on the search engine in multiple computers I own and different browsers:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you clarify how you configured robots.txt. If it disallows that URL then bots can't crawl it to read your meta tags.

Comment: For sure @TonyMcCreath. Text included in edited post

Comment: What Stephen said

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, *robots.txt* `Disallow` is not compatible with meta `noindex` tags.   Because disallowing in *robots.txt* prevents crawling, it means that Googlebot will never see the `noindex` and may continue to index your website.  When Google indexes sites that are blocked by *robots.txt* it shows them without knowing the words that are on the page.  See [How to resolve Google “Indexed, though blocked by robots.txt”](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/117744/how-to-resolve-google-indexed-though-blocked-by-robots-txt)

You should allow Googlebot to crawl your entire site so that it sees the `noindex` meta tags.  Your robots.txt file should look like:

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow:
```

You should ensure that the `<meta name="robots" content="noindex">` is on **every page of your site**.  If you put it on just your home page, then only your home page will get de-indexed.  There is no need to use the second tag just for Googlebot because Googlebot obeys either.

Once your tags are on your site, Googlebot will de-index your pages within 24 hours of next crawling them.  It may take Google a couple months to re-crawl your entire site and remove the whole thing from its index.

To speed up the process you can continue to use the [Google URL removal tool](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/removals).   The problem with the tool is that it only allows you to remove one page at a time.   If you have lots of pages indexed, it could take a lot of work to use that tool for all your pages.