# Will a robots noindex meta tag completely prevent search engines from indexing a page?

Tags: seo, html, search-engines, meta-tags, noindex

I am wondering if meta tag `<meta name="robots" content="noindex,follow">` will completely prevent a website page from being indexed.

What if user has registered website from Google Webmaster console will `noindex` still prevent google from indexing this page?

What if the website has sitemap which is submitted to Google using search console, will `noindex` still stop google from indexing website pages?

I would like clarity as to the precedence that takes place in these situations.

If the tag were instead`<meta name="robots" content="index,follow">`, what will happen in that case?

Answer (score 2):

A robots meta tag with `noindex` will prevent Google from indexing a page.  The meta tag takes precedence over:

- Search console account: Registering for search console will show you additional information about how Google views your site, but it doesn't affect whether or not it is indexed.
- Inclusion in an XML sitemap:  Including a noindex page in a sitemap will not cause the page to get indexed.  It will cause Google to report a problem with the sitemap in Google Search Console.

A robots meta tag does **NOT** take precedence over *robots.txt*.   If you disallow a page in robots.txt and also include the meta tag,  Googlebot will not crawl the page.  It won't be able to see the meta tag.   As a result, the [disallowed page may still get indexed](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/117744/how-to-resolve-google-indexed-though-blocked-by-robots-txt) in some (fairly rare) circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply change the meta tag. If the meta tag is the same on all pages, probably it should be `<meta name="robots" content="index,follow">` on each page so that the website be indexed completely as you have a sitemap already.