# How do I fix the Indexed, though blocked by robots.txt issue if the reported pages do not exist at all?

Tags: google-search-console

I found some related information like [How to resolve Google "Indexed, though blocked by robots.txt"](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/117744/how-to-resolve-google-indexed-though-blocked-by-robots-txt) but it's not answering my question.

The pages I saw in the report do not exist at all.

[image]

For instance, the two links above do not exist at all. I don't know why people add some number or an `image?url=` to my URL. It's so weird.

How can I tell Google just to ignore these URLs?

Comment: What HTTP status do those URL return?  Is it a "404 Not Found"?   Are those URLs currently blocked in your robots.txt?

Answer (score 1):

If a URL is blocked by robots.txt, Google can't crawl it to discover if it exists or not.

Google is probably aware of the URL via a link to it, or even an old link to it. Once Google is made aware of a URL it will report on it. In this case it is telling you the robots.txt file is not letting it crawl the URL to find out more about it.

Comment: What do I need to do to fix it?

Comment: Consider it a non issue.You could stop blocking those URLs so Google can crawl and see they don't exist. But they you would worry about the 404 warnings it would report. The only activity of value is to try and remove/fix any links to those URLs.