# Prevent search engines from crawling and indexing all domains and subdomains set up under an Apache server

Tags: htaccess, apache, web-crawlers

My company is renting a CentOS server, with one main domain and ~30 subdomains (the number varies, but it's usually around 30) hosted on it. The subdomains themselves are used for various purposes (mostly development), and are usually deleted once they outlive their use.

The setup is as follows

```
public_html / 
    maindomain_com
    subdomain1_maindomain_com
    subdomain2_maindomain_com
    .
    .
    .
    subdomain30_maindomain_com
    subdomain31_maindomain_com
    .
    .
```

Recently it has come to our attention that some of the search engines have indexed some of our defunct and some of our active subdomains.

What would be the best way of preventing search engines and crawlers from crawling and indexing the main site and its subdomains?

I am aware that it's possible to create a `robots.txt` file with `noindex, nofollow, etc` directives, but I'd like to avoid it, if possible (going through ~30 subdomains, setting up a new `robots.txt` when a new subdomain is created, etc).

I'm also aware that it's possible to use:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, noarchive, nosnippet, nofollow, noodp, noydir"
</IfModule>
```

in `.htaccess`. What I'm unsure of is whether I could place this directive inside of main domain's `.htaccess`, in hopes of preventing crawling for both the main domain and its subdomains.

Is there a better way of doing this? I've come across [a StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14778483/6133426) that `Alias` can be used in `httpd.conf` for `robots.txt`. Can this be used for `.htaccess` as well?

Comment: Crawling and indexing are two different things.  It is usually impossible to totally prevent both.   You can either prevent all crawling and accept that a URL or two occasionally gets indexed, or you can allow crawling and prevent indexing.

Comment: Robots.txt doesn't support `nofollow`.  Google used to support `noindex` in robots.txt [but no longer does](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/84884/how-does-noindex-in-robots-txt-work).   The only relevant robots.txt directive that is available is `Disallow:`.

Comment: Why do you want a `.htaccess` solution rather than something for `httpd.conf`?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Thank you for the first two remarks, I'll keep them in mind. As for the `.htaccess` solution, it seemed to be the easiest to implement in case a crawlable domain is added to the server. But in this case, it's only one main domain, and xy subdomains.

Comment: Do all of these subdomains have the same document root are are you serving them out of different directories?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Every subdomain has its own directory. I've added the structure of `public_html` to my question.

Comment: "place this directive inside of main domain's .htaccess" - Although from your file structure it looks like subdirectory `maindomain_com` that presumably serves the main domain's content is at the same level as the subdomain directories?

Comment: @MrWhite `maindomain_com` serves the main domain's content, and all of the subdomains are on the same level, and have contents of their own.